# How can I call event from webpack bundle if event written in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

How can I call event from webpack bundle if event written in HTML file?

**Part of HTML layout:**

```
<button class="l-dropbtn" onclick="openDropDown()">
   <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</button>
```

**index.js :**

```
import * as frame from "./common/frame.js";
```

**frame.js :**

```
export function openDropDown() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("l-dropdown")[0].classList.toggle("is- 
hidden");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
   const dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("l-dropdown")[0];
   const trgt = event.target;
   if (!dropdown.matches(".is-hidden") && !(trgt.matches('.l-dropbtn') || trgt.matches('.fas')))
      dropdown.classList.add("is-hidden");
   }
```

When I create a bundle, HTML file can't see `openDropDown()`! How can I resolve that, without delete `onclick` in a layout(prefer) or with deleting if that more relevant?

Comment: how about trying frame.openDropDown?

Comment: Don`t see frame, I`m trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting functions in webpack will not make them global. You could try attaching the function directly to the window object in `frame.js`:

```
window.openDropDown = openDropDown;
```

This *kinda* goes against what webpack is mainly used for, which is modular bundling of your code.

Comment: How can I add window event in this situation?

Comment: currently your `window.onclick = fun...` code is a side effect of importing the module in `frame.js`. A better approach would be to encapsulate the side effect in a function, that you'll import and call when appropriate, e.g. after page load.